# Count number of occurrences of a value in Lua table

Tags: lua, count, lua-table

Basically what I want to do is convert a table of this format

```
result={{id="abcd",dmg=1},{id="abcd",dmg=1},{id="abcd",dmg=1}}
```

to a table of this format:

```
result={{id="abcd",dmg=1, qty=3}}
```

so I need to know how many times does `{id="abcd",dmg=1}` occur in the table. Does anybody know a better way of doing this than just nested `for` loops?

Comment: is it  no option to store the info like this? sometDmgTable.abcd = {1,1,1} or simply increase some total dmg value instead of counting dmg1 objects?

Comment: That's not what its about, basically the id and the damage value together make up an object, it might as well be `result={{str="abcd:1"}, {str="abcd:1"}, {str="abcd:1"}}` to `result={{str="abcd:1", qty = 3}`

Comment: Are they the same objects, or objects with identical contents?

Comment: Identical contents, it's needed to parse some kind of config file. I basically need to notice when the user wants one behavior more than once and how often. The behavior is defined by an id plus a dmg number.

Answer (score 5):

```
result={{id="abcd",dmg=1},{id="defg",dmg=2},{id="abcd",dmg=1},{id="abcd",dmg=1}}

local t, old_result = {}, result
result = {} 
for _, v in ipairs(old_result) do
  local h = v.id..'\0'..v.dmg
  v = t[h] or table.insert(result, v) or v
  t[h], v.qty = v, (v.qty or 0) + 1
end

-- result: {{id="abcd",dmg=1,qty=3},{id="defg",dmg=2,qty=1}}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the script you've used above?

Comment: local h = v.id..'\0'..v.dmg
  v = t[h] or table.insert(result, v) or v
  t[h], v.qty = v, (v.qty or 0) + 1, I'm just not sure what you're doing. Sorry very new to lua and trying to solve a similar problem

Comment: @Bee - I'm saving (and incrementing counter on each occurrence) all items to the table `t` using concatenated string as table index

Answer (score 0):

So you want to clear duplicate contents, although a better solution is to not let dupe contents in, here you go:

```
function Originals(parent)
    local originals = {}
    for i,object in ipairs(parent) do
        for ii,orig in ipairs(originals) do
            local dupe = true
            for key, val in pairs(object) do
                if val ~= orig[key] then
                    dupe = false
                    break
                end
            end
            if not dupe then
                originals[#originals+1] = object
        end
    end
    return originals
end
```

I tried to make the code self explanatory, but the general idea is that it loops through and puts all the objects with new contents aside, and returns them after.

*Warning: Code Untested*